# How to impute missing values with groupby if the group has less than 3 nan

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe has 3 columns of "type", "State", "price", with missing values in price column.

Sample Dataframe:

```
type   state   price

CHR     NSW     1.2
CHR     VIC     nan
Kia     NSW     2
```

I want to impute missing values if there are less than 3 nan in "price" column after groupby based on both "type" and "State", otherwise nan.

Some codes looks like the below:

```
> df_daily_grouped = df_daily.groupby(['type', 'State'])
> df_daily_grouped["price"] = df_daily_grouped("price").transform(lambdax: x.fillna(x.mean()) if x.count() < 3, axis=1 )
```

Thanks

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe, with expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy just added a sample. Please see the updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try slightly modify your solution

```
df_daily_grouped['price'].transform(lambda x : x.fillna(x.mean()) if x.isnull().sum()<3 else x)
```

Comment: I have 44449 records in the dataframe. I've got the below error

`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 44207 elements, new values have 44449 elements`

Comment: @AmnKh drop the NaN from both type and state